# Is the Poincare inequality or the log-Sobolev inequality a sufficient condition to satisfy the isoperimetric inequality?

Tags: inequality, concentration-of-measure

I am trying to find any link between these inequalities. Either poincare --> isoperimetry or Log-Sobolev --> isoperimetry. Is there any work regarding this? If not how can I proof this?